# Why do treadmill amperages fluctuate?

Tags: current-measurement, power-measurement, power-meter

Multiple sources describe monitoring a treadmill’s current as an indicator of friction. When it increases, it’s time to add silicone oil between the deck and the undersurface of the belt. One good site is at https://hnpfit.com/amp-draw-tell-us/.

The easiest tool to monitor amperage appears to be a “power meter,” as popularized by the Kill A Watt brand. But the displayed amperages fluctuate wildly. “Plug the machine back in, turn the power switch on and proceed with your readings. They will jump around quite a bit, take an average of the numbers you see displayed.”

Even with no load (no one on the belt) and a constant velocity, the displayed current readings randomly vary over a range of an ampere or more. The same meter shows a constant current with a simple resistive load like a coffee percolator beginning to heat up.

Why is this measurement of a treadmill’s current so apparently unstable?

Comment: "*... current readings randomly vary over a range of an ampere or more.*" Is that significant? What's the average reading?

Comment: If nothing else, the belt isn't going to wear perfectly uniformly so friction will vary as a function of position.  The velocity also probably isn't perfectly constant since the control loop will have some instantaneous error.  There may be more complex sources of variance as well, but you'd have to pull apart the system to see what its doing.

Comment: One possible simple explanation could be that it's PWM based and the measurement system is too crude to catch that. Measure current using a known resistor to ground with an oscilloscope.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: Don't trust everything you read on the internet. It may be completely bogus, or at worst only true in the most literal sense under extremely well controlled conditions.

> Why is this measurement of a treadmill’s current so apparently unstable?

Because the actual current varies so much. Friction is roughly proportional to the normal (vertical) load on the belt. The ground reaction forces between a foot and the treadmill belt vary a lot during the gait cycle. In normal walking gait, the highest normal force is during the heel strike, and may be several times above the average force.

When running, these forces drop down to zero when neither foot is touching the belt. That's how running differs from walking gait.

> Multiple sources describe monitoring a treadmill’s current as an indicator of friction.

I call BS on that. This is, unfortunately, the sort of thing that people copy and paste, try out, it doesn't work, they think they are doing something wrong but it "should work, right?" (not!), and still keep their ad-laden "articles" (monkeys typing on keyboards) up.

One really needs to understand basics of a few different disciplines to do it.

First of all, as you've noticed the current varies so much that you can't just "read it". What you *can* do is to run the treadmill in well controlled conditions, measure the *energy* use over a constant period time, i.e. the difference in the kWh at the start and end of test interval, and *then* compare the results over time.

Those "well controlled conditions" are really hard to achieve all at once:

- same ambient air temperature within +/-2C,
- same ambient humidity within +/-10%,
- same mains voltage within +/-5V,
- same insolation of the treadmill and the test subject (!),
- same walker/runner who is in good enough shape to maintain highly repeatable gait day after day, week after week, month after month,
- no injuries to the test subject, as those affect the gait (!),
- test subject weighs in to within at +/-0.5% of their reference body weight before each test,
- same belt speed,
- same gait (*either* walking or running, same every time!),
- dedicated running shoes, in good shape (say <50 miles on them), sparsely used  only for data collection, not for general exercise,
- data acquisition starts either with a cold treadmill - in the first seconds after getting running, or after the treadmill reached thermal equilibrium with environment after about an hour (yes),
- the treadmill actually had time to fully cool down from last use if the data is taken on a "cold" treadmill,
- ...

So yeah, if you can get your data in such well-controlled conditions, then sure, the only thing left affecting the energy use of the treadmill is belt lubrication. Otherwise the data you'll get will be all over the place. Yes, the conditions need to be very well controlled. Otherwise, you can get significant changes that well exceed any effects of lubrication just from changing your posture, shoes, and overall conditioning, keeping everything else the same.

So yeah, I still call BS on all the "sources". What they describe is the kind of a test people do in research labs. For treadmill lubrication, use a fixed schedule based on hours of use or miles. That's all. No need to measure any currents.

And, if you're the repeat user of the same treadmill, in quiet conditions at home, then you should be able to tell the lubrication state by ear, over days and weeks of use. There'll be multiple sound sources that our auditory system will integrate. Over several months of daily treadmill use with lubrication, your brain will likely start noticing differences without you even trying.

I'm a mechanical engineer by training. I love to measure stuff. I have a treadmill. I designed the things, too. I don't even know how much current that thing is consuming in my typical use case. I don't need to care just to use it correctly. Neither should you. Unless you're curious. Then you're off on a research project. That may be super-informative, educational, and curiosity-satisfying. But do you care?

Comment: Interest only: I "some while ago" designed exercise machine controllers for Taiwanese manufactured equipment.